# In Scala is it possible to create class object of class which takes generic

Tags: scala, generics

In the code below at runtime the value will just be an instance of class list.
Is it possible to create an instance of class List[T] using typetags or classtags?

```
  private def method[T <: Product](clazz: Class[T]) = {
    val value: Class[List[T]] = classOf[List[T]]
  }
```

Comment: You can call the `runtimeClass` method of a **ClassTag** to get **Class[T]**, from which you could call the [`newInstance()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--). From there, you will have to play with Java reflection. In any case, in runtime you will have a **List**, you can not create an instance of **List[Int]**, because such instance will never exist in runtime.

Comment: In order to create an instance of List[T], you need to have some sort of value. Where do you expect that to come from?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Could you put it into a broader context? How would you use that created `List[T]`? The problem is that JVM uses type erasure for generics so there really just `List[_]` at runtime and `T` is lost. On the other hand given `List` is covariant in `T`, `Nil`  can work as `List[T]` for any `T` so again your real problem is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def create[A: ClassTag](): List[A] = List.empty[A]
create[Int]()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.